# React Hooks -- Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on the freeCodeCamp drum machine app. In my app with function arrow components, I set state of `display` with the useState hook in the parent component and pass it as a prop to the child component. In the parent component, I try to render the `display` state in a div. However, when the method is triggered (on click of the "drum pad" div), the app crashes. In the console I get an error that says "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {display}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." 
I've been following along a YouTube tutorial for this project but using arrow function components and Hooks instead of regular classes as used in the tutorial--in the tutorial (around 1:55 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sqb5oMIa4yo)) the person successfully does what I'm trying to do, so I think the issue is something to do with using Hooks or arrow function components.

```
// APP COMPONENT (PARENT)

const sounds = [
  { id: 'snare', letter: 'Q', src: 'https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/snare.mp3' },
  // etc.
];

const App = () => {

  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(''); // <----

  const handleDisplay = display => { // <----
    setDisplay({ display });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="drum-machine">
        <div className="display">
          <p>{display}</p> // <---- Related to error in console
        </div>
        <div className="drum-pads">
          {sounds.map(sound => (
            <DrumPad
              id={sound.id}
              letter={sound.letter}
              src={sound.src}
              handleDisplay={handleDisplay} // <----
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// DRUMPAD COMPONENT (CHILD)

const DrumPad = ({ id, letter, src, handleDisplay }) => {

  let audio = React.createRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
    audio.current.play();
    audio.current.currentTime = 0;
    handleDisplay(id); // <----
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="drum-pad"
      id={id}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <p className="letter">{letter}</p>
      <audio
        ref={audio}
        id={letter}
        src={src}
      >
      </audio>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: {JSON.stringify(display)} or make display value simply a string instead of an object. setDisplay(display)

Comment: `setDisplay({ display });` is converting whatever the value `display` is to an object that looks like this: `{"display": DISPLAYSTRING}`. This happens due to a JS mechanic called Destructuring (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). As the previous comment mentions, using `setDisplay(display)` will make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the state as an object instead of a string. Remove the curly brackets around it.

```
const handleDisplay = display => {
  setDisplay(display);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered, but since you are following a tutorial, I am assuming you are learning React and wanted to point a couple of things to help you :)

The incorrect use of state was pointed out, but just for clarification (and the reason I think you were using an object): in the "old" way, with Class components, the state used to be an object, and you needed to update it like an object. This [example here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) shows that. With Hooks, you don't need to set the whole State object, only that specific state property. More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#recap).

Another point is, in your CodePen example at least, you were missing the import for `useState`. You either need to import it like this `import { useState } from React` or use it like this `React.useState`, since this is a separate module, not imported by default when you import React.

The last point is, when creating components using a loop (like your `<DrumPad>` with the `map`) you need to [provide a "key" attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). that will help React keep track of things that needs to be updated or rerendered.

O updated your code with those changes in this link, if you wanna see it working:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-browser-zkum2

Good luck and hope you are enjoying React Hooks :)